# Regex to seperate concatenated phone number and email

Tags: php, regex

I have strings where unfortunately phone number and email are concatenated like this:

`$phone_email = "617.651.3123mya123@some-site.com";`

I'd like to be able to split between the last number and first letter.

**Desired output**

```
$phone = "617.651.3123";
$email = "mya123@some-site.com";
```

I'm using php but hopefully the strategy would be straightforward in any language.

**EDIT**

I've tried many things including trying to simply grab the email by removing the digits. `$email = preg_replace('#^\d+#', '', $phone_email);` That results in removing only the `617` ignoring the `.`

Comment: Show us what you've tried and what didn't work. Then we have something to start with.  Also, please describe the rules, in English, that you want to implement in a regular expression.  How do you know what's phone number and what's email?

Comment: @anubhava: That will be broken if the email address starts with a number.

Comment: @AndyLester I've tried many things including trying to simply grab the email by removing the digits. `$email = preg_replace('#^\d+#', '', $phone_email);` That results in removing only the `617` ignoring the `.`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out, splitting between "the last number and first letter" may not be a good strategy, since email addresses can start with numbers. That said, I believe this does roughly what you asked for:

```
$phone_email = "617.651.3123mya123@some-site.com";

$matches = [];
preg_match("/([^a-zA-Z]*)(.*)/", $phone_email, $matches);

$phone = $matches[1];
$email = $matches[2];

echo "Phone: $phone\n";
echo "Email: $email\n";

// Output:
// Phone: 617.651.3123
// Email: mya123@some-site.com
```

Comment: thanks, how about to catch where the `$phone_email` lacks the phone number?

Comment: Can there be some catch for the `@`?

Comment: See my edit. Use a `*` instead of `+` in the first capture.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution is:

```
$phone_email = "617.651.3123mya123@some-site.com";
$ms = array();
preg_match("/(.*\d)([a-z].*)/", $phone_email, $ms);
print_r($ms);
```

Of course cases when email starts with a number are not considered.

Comment: I don't think this even works on the input you've tested with, right?

Comment: My only remaining suggestion would be to handle uppercase letters as well, though I admit the original question is very underspecified.

Answer (score 1):

split after digits and points repetitions

```
print_r(preg_split('/(\d+\.?)+\K/', $phone_email,2));
```

**[demo](https://eval.in/606101)**

Comment: Output: `Array
(
    [0] => 617.
    [1] => 651.3123mya123@some-site.com
)`